# Maximum of 2 numpy unint8 arrays

Tags: numpy, max, where-clause

I want to get the maximum of 2 numpy uint8 arrays (0 to 255) but I want to exclude the 255 value.

```
x1 = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 255]], dtype=np.uint8)
x1 = np.array([[2, 2], [255, 255]], dtype=np.uint8)

result:
array([[2, 2], [2, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

How to do that efficiently ?

Comment: I answered but didn't see the *exclude 255* part? What do you mean with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple trick using over- and underflow.

```
>>> np.maximum(x1+1, x2+1)-1
array([[  2,   2],
       [  2, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: fiddling with the bits ~ bit fiddling

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [np.maximum()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 255]], dtype=np.uint8)
x2 = np.array([[2, 2], [255, 255]], dtype=np.uint8)

print(np.maximum(x1, x2))
#[[  2   2]
# [255 255]]
```

**EDIT**

In other answer you have the actual solution, which I edited for multiple array use:

```
x1 = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 255]], dtype=np.uint8)
x2 = np.array([[2, 2], [255, 255]], dtype=np.uint8)
x3 = np.array([[4, 255], [2, 255]], dtype=np.uint8)

reduce(np.maximum, np.stack((x1, x2, x3))+1)-1
#[[  4   2]
# [  2 255]]
```